# balls and urns problem

Tags: combinatorics

Here's the problem:

Two balls, $a$ and $b$ are distributed in three urns labelled, $1$, $2$, and $3$. With the order of occupancy in a given urn irrelevant, the outcomes of the experiment are nine in number

I have a problem: I can’t formalise it. As I see distinguishable (ball $a$, $b$) in distinguishable (urn: $1,2,3$) I think “statistical physics” and in particular the (hypothetical) Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

However the formulas that I developed back then seem not to check out in this case; is that because the number of balls is less than the urns?

I want a general formula describing the balls per urn especially in the case of number of balls < number of urns.

Comment: Assuming that an urn can contain arbitrarily many balls, then there are $u^b$ possibilities (where $u$ is the number of urns and $b$ the number of balls).  But perhaps you wanted more constraints?

Comment: that's good for now, thanks, i think i am trying to solve it s a partitioning problem, which brought me in the wrong direction